# Can not download SkyLake GuC - 6.1

Tags: intel, ubuntu-gnome

I tried to download Skylake Guc - 6.1 from here [Here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/skylake-guc-6.1) . But there i found no option to download. What am i doing wrong ? Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

The link is missing from the page.

You can still download it directly, like this:

`curl -s -f https://01.org/sites/default/files/downloads/intelr-graphics-linux/sklgucver61.tar.bz2`

*OR*

`wget https://01.org/sites/default/files/downloads/intelr-graphics-linux/sklgucver61.tar.bz2`